# ksh + while loop + get the same file with the same spaces

Tags: ksh

need advice about the following

with the following ksh script I actually copy file1 to file2 
my problem is that lines in file2 are not with the same location as file1

```
 #!/bin/ksh

 while read -r line ; do 
 echo $line >> file2
 done < file1
```

for example

```
more file1
  line1
      line2
         line3


more  file2
line1
line2
line3
```

the question what I need to change in my script in order to get lines location as described in file1? after I run my ksh script?

lidia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set IFS=

```
while IFS= read -r line ; do echo "$line"; done<file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
while read -r line ; do 
echo $line | sed -re 's/^\s+//' >> file2
done < file1
```

This uses sed to get rid of the leading whitespaces present in lines from file1.